# c# - return plain text from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to return plain text from web api by just modifying the global.ashx cause I've seen a lot of answers but they all suggested the same which is to convert the return type of each method to plain text in the web api controller?

Comment: What do you get if you do like `return "Hello"` from a method with signature like `public string Test()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11581697/2074346

Comment: @SerhiyChupryk What I'm getting is an XML

Comment: @KishoreSahas yes I've already seen that but what I want to achieve is a Global settings for all my webapi.

Comment: have you tried setting in  `Application_BeginRequest` ? as `protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        }`