# ASP.NET Core HTTPRequestMessage returns strange JSON message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I am currently working with ASP.NET Core RC2 and I am running into some strange results.
So I have an MVC controller with the following function:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Tunnel() {
    var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    message.Content = new StringContent("blablabla", Encoding.UTF8);
    message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
    message.Headers.CacheControl = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue {
        NoCache = true
    };

    return message;
}
```

If I call this with postman with an Accept header set to text plain I get this response:

```json
{
  "Version": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 1,
    "Build": -1,
    "Revision": -1,
    "MajorRevision": -1,
    "MinorRevision": -1
  },
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "text/plain"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Cache-Control",
      "Value": [
        "no-cache"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

I really do not understand how this is the generated reponse to the above controller. It is basically a JSON serialization of the entire message itself and does in no way contain the "blablabla" I intended to send.

The only way I have gotten the desired result is by making my controller function return `string` instead of `HttpResponse`, but that way I am unable to set headers like `CacheControl`

So my question is: why do I get this strange response? It seems like very weird behaviour to me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749928/mvc6-web-api-return-plain-text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853072/how-to-return-file-from-asp-net-5-web-api

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/), ASP.NET Core MVC does not support `HttpResponseMessage`-returning methods by default.

If you want to keep using it, you can, by using WebApiCompatShim:

1. Add reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` to your project.
2. Configure it in `ConfigureServices()`: `services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();`
3. Set up route for it in `Configure()`:

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapWebApiRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
   ```

Comment: @Iarzz11, this answer should be accepted. It worked well for me.

Comment: I added the `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim":"1.1.0"` to my `project.json` but got this error: `Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)` i used all other `version` numbers, still getting the same error.

Comment: @HasanAYousef I think you need to add something like `"imports": [ "portable-net45+win8" ]` under the `"netcoreapp1.1"` node in your project.json. (But I haven't tested this.)

Comment: Setting up routes is not required if all you need is to be able to return an `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: Microsoft have since documented this in detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.0#microsoftaspnetcoremvcwebapicompatshim

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `Cache-Control` header with string content, try this:

```
[Produces("text/plain")]
public string Tunnel()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    return "blablabla";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core, modify the response as it travels through the pipeline. So for headers, set them directly as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37441642/6651). (I've tested this for setting cookies.) You can also set the HTTP status code this way.

To set content, and therefore use a specific formatter, follow the documentation [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting). This enables you to use helpers such as `JsonResult()` and `ContentResult()`.

A complete example translating your code might be:

```
[HttpGet("tunnel")]
public ContentResult Tunnel() {
    var response = HttpContext.Response;
    response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = CacheControlHeaderValue.NoCacheString;
    return ContentResult("blablabla", "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```