# Returning a PDF from an ASP.NET Core 2 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to return a PDF file from my ASP.NET Core 2 controller.
I have this code
(mostly borrowed from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486431/return-pdf-to-the-browser-using-asp-net-core)):

```
var net = new System.Net.WebClient();
//a random pdf file link
var fileLocation = "https://syntera.io/documents/T&C.pdf";/
var data = net.DownloadData(fileLocation);
MemoryStream content = null;
try
{
    content = new MemoryStream(data);
    return new FileStreamResult(content, "Application/octet-stream");
}
finally
{
    content?.Dispose();
}
```

This code above is part of a service class that my controller calls. This is the code from my controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    var result = await _downloader.DownloadFileAsync(fileName);
    return result;
}
```

But I keep getting `ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.`

The try and finally block was an attempt to fix it , from another SO question .

The main question is A) Is this the right way to send a PDF file back to the browser and B) if it isn't, how can I change the code to send the pdf to the browser?

Ideally , I don't want to first save the file on the server and then return it to the controller. I'd rather return it while keeping everything in memory.

Comment: What was the exact code *before* you added the `try`/`finally`? That `try`/`finally` is sure to cause an `ObjectDisposedException` so it'd be useful to see what was going on before you introduced it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `finally` will always get called (*even after the `return`*) so it will always dispose of the content stream before it can be sent to the client, hence the error.

> *Ideally , I don't want to first save the file on the server and then return it to the controller. I'd rather return it while keeping everything in memory.*

Use a [`FileContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class to take the raw byte array data and return it directly.

> **FileContentResult**: Represents an `ActionResult` that when executed will write a binary file to the response.

```
async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFileAsync(string fileName){
    using(var net = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
        byte[] data = await net.DownloadDataTaskAsync(fileName);
        return new FileContentResult(data, "application/pdf") {
            FileDownloadName = "file_name_here.pdf"
        };
    }
}
```

No need for the additional memory stream

Answer (score 1):

You must specify :

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf");
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf")
```

For the file to be **opened directly** in the browser.

Comment: This really isn't going to help with the `ObjectDisposedException`.