# ABCpdf - Download PDF with .NET Core 2.1 - HttpContext/HttpResponse

Tags: asp.net-core, httpresponse, httpcontext, abcpdf

I'm creating a web page that will allow the user to download a report as a PDF using ABCpdf. But reading the documentation, the only options I see are by using `doc.Save("test.pdf")` (which saves the file on the server that is hosting the application) or using `'HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();'` (which saves on the client side, which is what I want, but HttpContext.Current is not available on .NET Core.

The band-aid solution I have is with the `doc.Save()`, I would save the file on the server then send a link to the view which then downloads it from the server. A potential risk I can think of is making sure to 'clean up' after the download has commenced on the server.

Is there a alternative/.NET Core equivalent for HttpContext.Current and also HttpResponse?

**Here is the code that I'd like to make work:**

```
byte[] theData = doc.GetData();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Expires = -1000;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", theData.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf"); 
Response.BinaryWrite(theData);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

**Errors I get (non-verbose)**

```
'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'ClearHeaders'
'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'ClearContent'
'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Expires'
'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'AddHeader'
'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'BinaryWrite'
'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated this answer to something that actually works!
**GetStream** does what you need, however to facilitate a file download in .NET Core it would be far easier if you create a controller as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1.
Then you can create a route controller to serve the file from the stream as shown in [Return PDF to the Browser using Asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486431/return-pdf-to-the-browser-using-asp-net-core).
So your controller would look something like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PDFController : Controller {
// GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        using (Doc theDoc = new Doc()) {
            theDoc.FontSize = 96;
            theDoc.AddText("Hello World");
            Response.Headers.Clear();
            Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
            return new FileStreamResult(theDoc.GetStream(), "application/pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Out of curiosity I just mocked this up and it does work - serving the PDF direct to the browser as download when you go to the URL *localhost:port/api/pdf*. If you make the content-disposition "inline; filename=test.pdf" it will show in the browser and be downloadable as test.pdf.

More information on the GetStream method here: https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2F5-abcpdf%2Fdoc%2F1-methods%2Fgetstream.htm

Comment: I actually haven't tried the original solution you had since I was having an issue with the length of the URI I was sending (I was trying to send the raw PNG). I'll try this out with a small HelloWorld, but thanks so much for looking into this!

Comment: You're welcome. It was academic curiosity. Just a reminder that ABCpdf have excellent support if you can't find it in the documentation: https://www.websupergoo.com/contactus.aspx ;-)