# Right way to implement downloading Excel file

Tags: .net, excel, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, closedxml

I have a .Net 6 Web API, which returns JSON data.

I am converting that JSON data and downloading it in UI(Blazor WebAssembly).

I saw [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039622/closedxml-return-file) and thought of the right way to implement this.

I also use Closedxml. It is Blazor today but it can be Angular in future.

So, is it better to return File from API end point and return JSON and let UI convert data to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your solution work in your future case (Angular) you should convert your json in excel in your API

The only benefit of converting the json in the client side is that there is less work for the server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).