# Why is Asp.net Core returning JSON instead of a CSV file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a web method that should return a CSV file for the browser to download when it is hit.  Instead, it is returning a JSON object that the browser simply displays.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("generate")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage GenerateCSV()
{
    var file = System.IO.File.Open("C:/some-path/invoice_import.csv", FileMode.Open);
    file.Position = 0;

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage();
    result.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    result.Content = new StreamContent(file);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "invoice_import.csv" };

    return result;
}
```

Here is the JSON that is returned:

```
{
  "version": {
    "major": 1,
    "minor": 1,
    "build": -1,
    "revision": -1,
    "majorRevision": -1,
    "minorRevision": -1
  },
  "content": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Length",
        "value": [
          "804"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": [
          "text/csv"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "Content-Disposition",
        "value": [
          "attachment; filename=invoice_import.csv"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": 200,
  "reasonPhrase": "OK",
  "headers": [],
  "requestMessage": null,
  "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

The intended function is for the browser to recognize that the response is a file and download that file.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.  I have referenced this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948809/web-api-return-csv-file) related to how I setup the C#.

The csv file exists and can be opened as a .csv with all of the proper data in it.  It seems it's an issue with getting the file to pass to the browser correctly.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove a lot of file generation because you said yourself that part worked.
You want to try to offer the smallest working code which describes your problem so that when people try to help you they don't have to work their way though so much code.

Comment: Is your client requesting JSON? If you are setting the Accept: application/json, or Content-Type: application/json in the request headers, the server may be honoring that request. Take a look through Fiddler, Postman, or whatever you want to view your request headers.

Comment: Does it do this if you use `Request.CreateResponse(...)`?

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin, I've tried setting the content-type and Accept headers of the request to "text/csv" (separately) and I still get the same response.

Comment: @Amy, I am using .net Core v1.1 and it appears that the Nuget Package (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core) that is required for Request.CreateResponse() is not available for this version of .net core

Comment: For those who also have this problem and land here, this is the answer that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37442851/5481661.  I also was creating my csv file in a using block and for some reason it was being disposed before the file was return so I had to remove the using block.