# ASP.Net Core API Accessing HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Net 4.5 application that I am trying to upgrade to ASP.Net Core.  This application receives calls from a 3rd party application.

In my old application I have an action that looks like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RealTimeAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var StatusMessage = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
```

From 4.5 this works fine.  However, when I use this code in ASP.Net core I get an "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object" error because request.Content is null.

The requests coming in to the two applications (4.5 and .Net Core) are the same.  Why is request.Content null in my .Net Core application?

When I referenced this post: [ASP.NET Core HTTPRequestMessage returns strange JSON message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429190/asp-net-core-httprequestmessage-returns-strange-json-message)

I tried installing the suggested Nuget Package.  However, it is not compatible with .Net Core:

> error: Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.2 is not compatible
>   with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.2 supports: error: - net45
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) error: -
>   portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81
>   (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=wp8+netcore45+net45+wp81+‌​wpa81)
>   error: One or more packages are incompatible with
>   .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code needs to be refactored to use more recent structure.

```
public Task<IActionResult> RealTimeAsync() {
    var StatusMessage = string.Empty;
    try {
        var request = this.Request;
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(request.Body); //request.Body returns a stream
    //...other code...
```