# Convert an object to Json in ASP.net Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, httpresponsemessage

I am trying to convert and object "Persona" to a json string in .net Framework 4 and i need help.

I have tried this (using System.Text.Json)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id){
  HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    Personas persona = context.tPersonas.FirstOrDefault(p => p.idPersona == id);
    if (persona != null){
      var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(persona);
      response.Content = new StringContent(jsonData);
      response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
      return response;
    }
  else
    return response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);            
}
```

And this (using Newtonsoft.Json);

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            Personas persona = context.tPersonas.FirstOrDefault(p => p.idPersona == id);
            if (persona != null)
            {
                response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persona));
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                return response;
            }
            else
                return response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);            
        }
```

When debugging, "persona" has data and "Serialize" shows null.

I tried also "Request.CreateResponse" but it is not recognized as a valid code for some weird reason.

Which step am I Skipping?

Comment: with Newtonsoft it is working. Your problem is not there  var persona = new{
  Name = "name",
  LastName = "lastname"
 };
 
 var st = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persona);

Comment: st variable ends null, don’t know why. Thoughts?

Comment: clean your solution, build and re-run it again, I personally tested it and it works

Comment: Thanks sir! It works as you said. Do you have any clue how to send that JSON in case of successful request and an error in case of failed one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `HttpResponseMessage` to return information in asp.core mvc, you need to complete the following steps.

- Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim`  package for your
  project.
- Add `services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();` to ConfigureServices in the starup.cs file.

Here is the code:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        Personas persona = _context.tPersonas.FirstOrDefault(p => p.idPersona == id);
        if (persona != null)
        {
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persona));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            response.Content = new StringContent("error message");
            return response;
        }

    }
```

**You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37442851/12884742).**

Here is the debug process from postman:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir! this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I use Minimal API, suggestions?